# PHP/cURL code not letting me select the link I want

Tags: php, curl

The problem is, the guide titled "*Alistar - Can you milk those?*" when clicked, gives me an error.

But if i click absolutely anything else on the page, it works perfectly fine. Is there a way, using cURL to be able click on that link? #

Edited: deleted content to avoid plagiarism risk.

Comment: Have you checked the source code / the contents of `$result`? That should give you a clue as to what is wrong or different.

Comment: I have checked the source code for both. And I cannot spot the difference.

Comment: @jeroen Do you have anything else I could check?

Comment: You should add the html of that section and specify what the error is.

Comment: @jeroen  Add what HTML where? I have already specified the error above. Sorry if I am answering you wrong, english is my not first language.

Answer (score 2):

The simple reason for it not working is that all the other links on the page are absolute URLs but the link you're asking about is a relative URL.

What that means is that the links that work start with the domain name so http://www.solomid.net/... while the link that doesn't work just starts with a / which means the web browser just uses the domain from the requested page.

Since you are fetching the contents of the page and displaying it on a different domain, the link does not work.

So the next question is how to get it to work?

The first step is to fix a "bug" in your code.  The line `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);` should have `1` or `true` as the third parameter instead of `0` because the way it's working right now is that `curl_exec($ch)` is returning `true` and the page contents is being output directly to the browser.

By setting `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);` you will have the page contents returned from `curl_exec` and stored in `$result`

Then the easiest fix would be to add the line:

```
$result = str_replace('<head>', '<head><base href="http://www.solomid.net/">', $result);
```

Which will insert the [HTML base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) into the head so the browser will use `http://www.solomid.net/` instead of the domain from the browser for URLs that are missing the domain.  Then when you `echo $result;` you will echo the slightly modified HTML contents and all the links should work.

Comment: Hello @andrewshell. Thanks for the comment. What am i meant to put in the () of the str_replace? I put the following: ("http://www.solomid.net/", "/guide/view/124099-aatrox-build-guide-fighter-by-jyarbz", $result) but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: +1 Nice first answer. Welcome here, and keep it up. :)

Comment: @user3306183 you should use str_replace('<head>', '<head><base href="http://www.solomid.net/">', $result).  The idea is to inject a base tag after the opening head tag.